# How to name a pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

When I create build pipeline they all have the same name in the builds sections of AP but with a number in parenthesis after.

How can I give it a custom name?

I googled it and the answer was to use visual designer but for me there is no longer an option to switch to visual designer.  I tried adding a `name` property to pipeline but this just name the build that is run, not the build configuration.

I would like to be able to see which of my builds I am running before running it.

Comment: See comments and status of [Cannot set pipeline name with yaml file in Azure Devops](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/437066/cannot-set-pipeline-name-with-yaml-file-in-azure-d.html). Not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah that feature is pretty hidden at the moment. I suppose it'll move to the settings panel soon, but now, depending on the pipeline features you've opted-in to, this is how to find the place to rename:

- <kbd>:</kbd> in the upper right corner next to <kbd>run</kbd>
- <kbd>⚡Triggers</kbd>
- <kbd>YAML</kbd>

[image]